# PHP file not putting file into folder

Tags: php, file, upload, save

I have tried numerous attempts at this code, i know the html is correct, but the PHP is tricky

```
<html>
<body>
<?php
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";
$uploaddir = '/var/www/Megan/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
$uploadfile);
echo "Stored in: " . "$uploaddir" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
?>
<h1>File upload successful!</h1>
<form method="get" action="/megan">
<input type="submit" value="Continue"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

help me fix this

Comment: check the file upload directory path.Also add form - attribute  enctype="multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this simple code, I think this will help you, and add your code as per your requirement.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 <input type="file" name="file" />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="upload" />
 </form>
<?php 
      $name=$_FILES['file']['name'];
      $temp=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
      $dir="var/www/Megan/";
      move_uploaded_file($temp,$dir.$name);
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. To start, your assumption that the HTML is correct is wrong. File upload forms need to be method="POST"
2. One of your form elements needs to be a file picker:

   ```
   <input type="file" name="file">
   ```
3. Your opening form tag needs an extra parameter:

   ```
   <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   ```
4. Your PHP should only run if the form has been POSTED, in which case the variable $_POST is set.  So put your php code inside a

   ```
   if($_POST) {
       //php here
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

may be your uploading directory is readonly or write protected

```
<?php
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
     echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

     $uploaddir = '/var/www/Megan/';
     $uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
     chmod($uploadfile, 0777);

     if($_FILES['file']['error']==0) {
         if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $uploadfile)){
            echo "Stored in: " . "$uploaddir" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
         } else {
            echo "error!!";
         }
     } else {
            echo "An error has occurred.<br/>Error Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"];
     }
?>
```